# I've got high accuracy in CNN model with transfer learning But lower accuracy in trainset

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I've got image classification model with CNN. I've done transfer learning using MobileNet. At the end of the Mobile Net, I added 4 layers to learn weights for my images(not update weights for MobileNet). Mobile Net's Weights are not changed. As a result, I've got 91% of accuracy with this model and evaluated with same training set(train _generator). But I've got lower accuracy about 41% at this time. Why different result is came out? I've used same training set though... Is there any difference with model.fit_generator's accuracy and model.evaluate_generator? or something wrong in data? Please help... How can I improve accuracy?? Here is my entire code below.

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, GlobalAveragePooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.applications import MobileNet
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.keras.applications.mobilenet import preprocess_input
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
```

```
base_model = MobileNet(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)

x=base_model.output
x=GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x=Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x)
x=Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x)
x=Dense(512, activation='relu')(x)
preds=Dense(7, activation='softmax')(x)

model=Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=preds)

for layer in model.layers[:-4]:
    layer.trainable=False
for layer in model.layers[-4:]:
    layer.trainable=True

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=preprocess_input)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('/Users/LG/Desktop/finger',
                                                   target_size=(224, 224),
                                                   color_mode='rgb',
                                                   batch_size=32,
                                                   class_mode='categorical',
                                                   shuffle=True)

model.compile(optimizer='Adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

step_size_train=train_generator.n//train_generator.batch_size
```

```
model.fit_generator(generator=train_generator,
                   steps_per_epoch=step_size_train,
                   epochs=10)
```

Epoch 1/10
17/17 [==============================] - 53s 3s/step - loss: 1.9354 - acc: 0.3026

Epoch 2/10
17/17 [==============================] - 52s 3s/step - loss: 1.1933 - acc: 0.5276

Epoch 3/10
17/17 [==============================] - 52s 3s/step - loss: 0.8936 - acc: 0.6787

Epoch 4/10
17/17 [==============================] - 54s 3s/step - loss: 0.6040 - acc: 0.7843

Epoch 5/10
17/17 [==============================] - 53s 3s/step - loss: 0.5367 - acc: 0.8080

Epoch 6/10
17/17 [==============================] - 55s 3s/step - loss: 0.2676 - acc: 0.9099

Epoch 7/10
17/17 [==============================] - 52s 3s/step - loss: 0.4531 - acc: 0.8387

Epoch 8/10
17/17 [==============================] - 53s 3s/step - loss: 0.3580 - acc: 0.8747

Epoch 9/10
17/17 [==============================] - 55s 3s/step - loss: 0.1963 - acc: 0.9301

Epoch 10/10
17/17 [==============================] - 53s 3s/step - loss: 0.2237 - acc: 0.9133

```
model.evaluate_generator(train_generator, steps=5)
```

[2.169835996627808, 0.41875]

Comment: You are using the same generator and not the same data. The generator's task is to augment images so that the model could generalise itself better. This could be a clear case of overfitting where the model performs better in training and performs badly on the validation dataset. The model performed well on the images which were generated while training. But, while inferencing, the generator produced different images which were not seen by the model before and hence the accuracy went down.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't know that the generator generates images randomly. So train_generator can be validation data as well as training data. Do you have any idea to avoid overfitting? Thanks!

Comment: Should I add this as the answer?